# How do I pass data from html/JavaScript page to a React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a working react application. If I render the component on the bottom of `App.js`, it works. It bundles everything together.

However, I would like to render the react component in the file that includes `bundle.js`.

So on the HTML page I have this code:

```
<script src="Scripts/ParsedRequests/dist/bundle.js"></script>
<script>
  var props = {
    rowData: { make: 'Toyota2', model: 'Celica', price: 35000 }
  };

  console.log(props);

  const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
  root.render(React.createElement(Main, props, null));
</script>
```

The error I am getting is: `ReactDOM is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

You should add the JS libraries in your HTML file, `React` and `ReactDOM`,  so you can use the functions in your JS code.

```html
  <div id="root"></div>
  
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>



  <script type="text/babel">
    var props = {
      rowData:
        { make: 'Toyota2', model: 'Celica', price: 35000 }

    };

    function Main(props) {
      console.log(props);
      return (
        <div>
          Make: {props.rowData.make}<br />Model: {props.rowData.model}<br />Price: {props.rowData.price}
        </div>
      );
    }

    const container = document.getElementById('root');
    const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(container);

    root.render(React.createElement(Main, props, null));

  </script>
```

You can read more about it on the official doc: https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html

Comment: Ok thanks, I added that - I wonder why I need to add it though because is it not included in the bundle.js file?

Now that I added it, I am getting this error:
Main is not defined

Comment: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/reactjs/reactjs.org/main/static/html/single-file-example.html You can have a look at this file

Comment: You should define the `Main` component

Comment: It is defined in the BUNDLE.js file

Comment: add the required code and bundle your project again and it should work

Comment: It works because if i put the code in app.

ReactDOM.render(< Main />, document.getElementById('root'));

It works, so I know its part of bundle.js (the main.js is bundled)

Comment: No I mean the Main is already part of the bundle.js file - and I have a reference to it